# How to retrieve a Date of Exported Files from the Data Loader tool

Tags: data-loader, dataloader.io

Is there a way to find out the Date of the exported files ("Data") from Salesforce? I meant, when was the time the data was exported from Salesforce.

Comment: you can get it from file's created date.

Comment: I can figure it out from File Description level from my pc but I want to know, if you can track who was the last person in the date data was exported from salesforce. I used Data Loader. This is a security concerns.

Comment: You can track like if they use standard Data Export option in setup audit trail.But if they use data loader like tools you can't track. @dave

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_troubleshooting.htm Please check, you can retrieve log entries from log file of Data Loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is available by way of the [Event Monitoring API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm). This is a paid feature, so you'll need to contact your account executive. It allows you to access the logs to see which user performed any particular query, accessed a particular page or record, etc. You can also request a [Log Analysis of User Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000212606&language=en_US), again a paid feature. Either of these features would allow you to determine which data was exported by a given user, the tool that was used, and so on.